# Spring boot with multiple datasource connecting to mysql and mongodb

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a web app using spring boot, Angular, mysql and mongodb. When I connect to multiple datasources, should I be writing separate code to persist the data in these DBs. I am extending JpaRepostiory and performing the CRUD operations.

I would like to know If there is a best practice I should follow while I deal with multiple datasources to avoid redundant code to persist the data

Answer (score 0):

Separate your repositories into different packages and add this into your configuration:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.acme.repositories.jpa")
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.acme.repositories.mongo")
interface Configuration { }
```

But I would also use `MongoRepository` so that it's obvious the repository is talking to MongoDB. It extends `CrudRepository` just like `JpaRepository` so you shouldn't need to change you code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am trying to understand the reason behind the separation. 

Is there any value add or Is that for maintenance ease? If I have to separate the repositories then I may have to rewrite few set of code which builds the object that has to be persisted or I should have it in a common place and use it across.

Also what will be inside the interface Configuration { }

Comment: Using two databases in one application is big design smell anyway. If you need to do it, it is crucial to be explicit about the underlying technology.

Comment: Ok. So I think your suggestion is to use the relevant repositories even if it requires redundancy based on the application. Can you please explain this phrase please 'big design smell anyway'

Comment: No I can't as SO is not forum for such discussions. You may want to try google or ask question on http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @luboskrnac wonder what makes you think that this question would be on-topic over there (as far as I can tell it would be kind of known poor fit: [Discuss this ${blog}](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6418/31260))

Comment: @gnat, so question: "What are pros and cons of connecting single application to multiple databases? Is it good practice? Why?" is not for softwareengineering.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @luboskrnac correct, see [What is the problem with "Pros and Cons"?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)

Comment: OK, so it it clearly isn't forum for such question. On the other hand softwareengineering just lost a lot of usefulness for me.

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: Thanks it helped me partially to find my solution